# micronaut already associated with parent beanfactory error running grails 4 app on standalone tomcat 8.5

Tags: grails, tomcat8, micronaut

Tomcat 8.5.71
Grails 4.0.11
RHEL 7.8

The application runs fine with the embedded tomcat but won't load with standalone.  Stacktrace is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gdbxt]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already associated with parent BeanFactory: io.micronaut.spring.context.factory.MicronautBeanFactory@347aa4db: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.setParentBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory.java:718)
at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.setParent(GenericApplicationContext.java:158)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.ParentContextApplicationContextInitializer.initialize(ParentContextApplicationContextInitializer.java:58)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:623)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:367)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 10 more

war file built for standalone tomcat has build.gradle with

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

I have

server:
port: 8091

in application.yml and also have the connector set to 8091 in the tomcat server.xml

This app is ported from grails 2.5.5. and is quite large with a number of additional dependencies.  It has quartz jobs which I disabled with quartz.pluginEnabled: false in application.yml.

It does get as far as running bootstrap.groovy since it prints out some logging from that code.

Can someone point me to a possible cause of this sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had created an extra package in the grails-app/init folder when migrating by creating a new grails 4 project and copying over the files from the grails2 project.  The error was due to trying to instantiate a second Application from the Application.groovy in that second init folder.  Surprising that it worked with the built in tomcat and run-app.